# How do I load an OpenGL function with the GTK4 GLContext using the Rust bindings

Tags: opengl, rust

I am wanting to start out with the most basic of OpenGL drawing, specifically, to put a triangle on the screen. I am using Rust and GTK4, and trying to use the `GLArea` (and `GLContext`) component provided in GTK4.

My problem is that there are some gaps in the documentation. The `gdk4::GLContext` component component says that I need to make the context current and then I can issue OpenGL commands:

[image]

But then the OpenGL library (https://crates.io/crates/gl) says that I must load functions:

[image]

In my `realize` or `render` callbacks, if I try to issue an OpenGL command, I just get a panic that the OpenGL function isn't loaded:

```
        gl_area.connect_realize(|ctx| {
            ctx.make_current();
            const VERTICES: [f32; 9] = [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, -0.5, 0.0];
            unsafe {
                gl::BufferData(
                    gl::ARRAY_BUFFER,
                    VERTICES.len() as isize,
                    VERTICES.as_ptr().cast(),
                    gl::STATIC_DRAW,
                );
            }
        });
```

GLContext doesn't load the functions and doesn't seem to provide a loader function.

How do I bridge the gap here?

Comment: I've had some success with Gtk3 with the `gl_loader` crate. Try calling `gl_loader::init_gl();` in `main()` and then you can use `gl::load_with(gl_loader::get_proc_address)` or maybe `gl::load_with(|s| gl_loader::get_proc_address(s) as *const _)`.

Comment: This seems to work in that I no longer get errors, but I can't say for sure that it would work because nothing is getting shown in my window. I'd like to mark this as an answer, but I basically can't prove that it's correct yet.

Answer (score 0):

In the [OpenGL](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/tree/master/examples/glium_gl_area) example given in the `gtk4-rs` [repository](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs), the [`epoxy`](https://crates.io/crates/epoxy)
crate is used to load the OpenGL function pointers like so:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Load GL pointers from epoxy (GL context management library used by GTK).
    {
        #[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
        let library = unsafe { libloading::os::unix::Library::new("libepoxy.0.dylib") }.unwrap();
        #[cfg(all(unix, not(target_os = "macos")))]
        let library = unsafe { libloading::os::unix::Library::new("libepoxy.so.0") }.unwrap();
        #[cfg(windows)]
        let library = libloading::os::windows::Library::open_already_loaded("epoxy-0.dll").unwrap();

        epoxy::load_with(|name| {
            unsafe { library.get::<_>(name.as_bytes()) }
                .map(|symbol| *symbol)
                .unwrap_or(ptr::null())
        });
    }

    // Rest of the GTK setup...
}
```

and then for each OpenGL function the adress is loaded like so

```rust
unsafe fn get_proc_address(&self, symbol: &str) -> *const std::ffi::c_void {
    epoxy::get_proc_addr(symbol)
}
```

as shown [here](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/blob/6814d2a2d55578ece1cdba640823c9835d6b4c1f/examples/glium_gl_area/glium_gl_area/mod.rs#L32).